# Unit Testing - not testable code converted to testable code

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have read so many places is that if your code is not test-able that mean code is not well written. So that makes me start writing a code that is test-able and to start using some unit testing framework.

With this though I start looking for some example with piece of code that is not testable and gradually converted to a testable code. I find tons of examples on unit testing but if someone can provide an example like above it probably can jump start things for me.

TIA

Comment: What unit testing framework are you looking to use? If you haven't decided, I would suggest using NUnit.

Comment: I disagree that code that is not unit-testable is not well written.  OO theory 101 says that you should make your code "do what its supposed to do" before you start implementing design patterns.  This prevents one from implementing patterns that simply won't work with the next change request.  Often, paradigms such as agile lead to code that is "requirements complete" cause the customer see's that it does what they want, but the developer is given no time to refactor as the customer see's only a finished product.  This is a management/process problem not "poorly written" but incomplete.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: every piece of code which should do what it is supposed to do has to be tested. That has nothing to do with applying an unneeded design pattern. Making code unit-testable means that you cannot even test your code, you can automatically repeat your tests. That is a real advantage when you are going to refactor your code.

Comment: @Doc I think you misunderstood me.  I don't believe you can seperate OO and dp's from unit-testability.  They are one in the same.  Applying no principles/writing "bad code"/code that can't be easily tested are similar concepts.  That's part of what drives the common belief that "bad code" can be equated with code that is not unit-testable.  Refactoring should wholly be a part of the development process and include these concepts which do make the code unit testable to begin with, applied at the end of the dev process.  Writing code that is unit testable to start leads to wasted abstraction.

Comment: @DOC you can CRUD or some common interface to help speed the dev process up with TDD, but that still requires planning of the OO and possibly dp's.  It also still doesn't free one from bloating method's, DRY, or keep other principles from being abused.

Comment: It is not really true that code that is not unit testable means that it is not well written. Code that is unit-testable is more abstracted, reusable, and configurable. However that might make the code less simple and harder to read and therefore harder to change. Sometimes that added abstraction, reusability, and configurability are exactly what you code needs, but if it only needs it in order to be testable, then you actually made your code worse not better. The advantage even in that case though is that now it is unit-testable, but not without a price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a bunch of [code in a button click event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton) and try to unit test it.  It's not impossible, but will either be non-trivial or require some copy-paste finagling to get it done.

```
protected void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currUser =
        User.Identity.Name.ToString().Trim()
            .Substring(User.Identity.Name.ToString().Trim()
            .IndexOf("\\") + 1);

    Inventory.Employee.DB objEmpDB = new Inventory.Employee.DB();
    Inventory.Employee.Details objEmpDetails = 
        new Inventory.Employee.Details();

    objEmpDetails = objEmpDB.Get(currUser);

    Welcome.Text = 
        "Current User: " + objEmpDetails.Employee_Full_Name;

    var objUserDetails = new Inventory.User.Details();
    Inventory.User.DB objUserDB = new Inventory.User.DB();

    if (objUserDB.UserAuthenticates(currUser))
    {
        objUserDetails = objUserDB.Get(currUser);
        currUserToken = objUserDetails.User_Token.Value;

        userID.Text = currUser;

        if (objUserDetails.Active_User_Name != objUserDetails.User_Name)
        {
            lShadow.Text = "Showin: " + objUserDetails.Active_User_Name;
            lServer.Text = "(" +
            objUserDB.UserPermissionName(objUserDetails.Active_Logon_Name)
                + ") - " + System.Environment.MachineName;
            lShadow.ToolTip = Inventory.Properties.Settings.Default
                .connectionString.Substring(0, Inventory.Properties
                .Settings.Default.connectionString.IndexOf(';'));
            divShadow.Visible = true;
        }
        else
            divShadow.Visible = false;

        lWelcome.Text = "Current User: " + objUserDetails.User_Name;
    }
}
```

Not only is this hard because of the difficulty of emulating a user button click, but look how much is going on in that button click.  If your unit test fails, there's about 100 freakin things that could have gone wrong. DRY, single concern, and other design principles lead to code that's easy to test and easy to fix.  After all, what good is a unit test if you are testing brigades rather than units :)

**UPDATE: (How to fix the above code)**
I'm not going to pretend that the code above is an easy fix.  That's a "small" sample from a code base I've worked on in the past.  I wanted to show how bad things can get in real life.

There's two major problems with the code.

1. Its hard to test button click
   events.
2. There's too much going
   on in one method.

Its easy to fix the Event driven/reproducing a button click event problem.  You can wrap all that code into another method:

```
protected void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EasyToCallMethod();
}

public void EasyToCallMethod()
{
    string currUser =
        User.Identity.Name.ToString().Trim()
        .Substring(User.Identity.Name.ToString().Trim().IndexOf("\\") + 1);
    //...rest of code
}
```

Now its easy to call from a unit test. But, that's a little silly because it really doesn't solve the second problem.

**Easy Fix**
So there's a good 15-20 tests that we can make out of this one method call.  Just make a test for each line that has a specific purpose (like where method calls are made) and you should have good unit tests that are small enough to tell where something broke and good code coverage.
**Advanced stuff**
Much more work can be done.  We can implement n-tier MVC or MVVM .  At some point, you have to ask yourself if you are over-engineering.  Unit tests should make your code more maintainable, but don't over-abstract yourself into nothingness.  This is where your own style and experience come into play.  When you feel like you've got the basics you should come back to SO with new questions or pickup a good book.

Comment: thank, how will you write this same code to make it testable?

Answer (score 7):

Here are two great books that will help you get started:

1. [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/)
2. [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for Working Effectively with Legacy Code.  Chock full of great examples. A must read for any budding TDDer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree completely. For example, let's assume you have a program which executes things based on a timer. If you wanted to test it in a deterministic way, you'd have to change and pause the system clock. There's tons of literature about deterministic testing of timed stuff. So everything is testable, the question is, how easily. And it doesn't depend on how well the code is written, it depends on the actual task that the program does and how it's designed, not implemented. Even with good designs, you can get code that is hard to test.

Comment: There are several good points, but I believe the OP is looking for a simple example that makes a unit test somewhat if not completely pointless.  I doubt he's looking for the theory of test complexity while still trying to grasp the basics of unit testing/TDD.

Answer (score 1):

The most important key factor to make code more (unit-) testable is dependency injection.

The first chapter of Mark Seemann's book

> Dependency Injection in .NET

is freely available here   http://www.manning.com/seemann/ as a PDF file. It contains a very complete example how to make a piece of tightly coupled code more testable by reducing the dependencies from lower layers.